# Find if there is a possible combination of values given a set a unique patterns

Tags: combinatorics

I have a set of Unique patterns of variables, where the patterns  = {ABC, AAC, ABD, BDD}, and the variables A=20, B=25, C=10, D=15.  I am looking at figuring out what pattern count will allow me to use all the variables.

example:
in my first run, I would fill a pattern {ABC} with {10,10,10} since C was the limited amount, leaving a remainder of A=10, B=15, C=0, D=5.  now that C is 0, I would just concentrate on the patterns that do not have C, {ABD, BBD}.  Next filling {ABD} with {5,5,5} since D is the limiter, leaving a remainder of A=5, B=10, C=0, D=0.  at this point I'm done with ABC=10, ABD=5, and a remainder of A=5, B=10.

I'm trying to come up with a formula that I can program so that if I have 6 patterns 5 variables deep with 10 different variables, the program can grind it out for a solution....

To add what I'm looking for: the set of formula i should use to find a solution that can be repeated. example : someone has a set of patterns {ABC, AAC, ABB, BCD, BCC, CDD} with A=215, B=155, C=125, D=200. how would I determine how many of each/which patterns would provide a solution with the lowest remainder. Consider the values in the patterns specific buckets that can only allow that variable.

A simple version would be : set of patterns {AB, BC} where A=10, B=15, C=9. The best solution would be AB=10, BC=5, with a remainder of C=4

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem via integer linear programming.  Let $I$ be the set of items, with demand $d_i$ for item $i\in I$.  Let $P$ be the set of patterns, and let $a_{i,p}$ be the number of copies of item $i\in I$ in pattern $p \in P$.  Let nonnegative integer variable $x_p$ be the number of copies of pattern $p$ used, and let nonnegative integer variable $r_i$ be the remainder (unsatisfied demand) for item $i$.

The optimization problem is to minimize $\sum\limits_{i \in I} r_i$ subject to $\sum\limits_{p \in P} a_{i,p} x_p + r_i = d_i$ for each $i \in I$.

For your first example, an optimal solution is $x_{ABC} = x_{ABD} = 10,  
x_{BDD} = 2, x_{AAC} = 0$, with remainders $r_A = 0, r_B = 3, r_C = 0, r_D = 1$, yielding objective value 4.

For your second example, an optimal solution is $x_{AAC} = 25, x_{ABB} = 77,
x_{BCD} = 1, x_{CDD} = 99$, with remainders $r_A = 88, r_B = r_C = 0, r_D = 1$, yielding objective value 89.

When the patterns are not predefined, this is a variant of the *cutting stock problem*.  The classical problem is to minimize $\sum\limits_{p\in P} x_p$ subject to $\sum\limits_{p \in P} a_{i,p} x_p \ge d_i$ for each $i \in I$, where each pattern has a weight capacity that limits which items it can contain.